# PHP calling ORA stored procedure: ORA-01722 invalid number

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures

I have this ORA stored procedure:

```sql
procedure calc(code in number, extLoan in number, loan in number, payment in number, duration in number, saleId in number, resultBlob out clob);
```

(currently only this header is available).

I have tried this PHP call (I am using `oci_*` functions directly, though we have a wrapper object for them):

```php
$query = '
BEGIN 
    calc(
        :code,
        :extLoan,
        :loan,
        :payment,
        :duration,
        :saleId,
        :result); 
END;';

$stmt = oci_parse($this->connection, $query);

oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':code', 100, 3, SQLT_INT);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':extLoan', 20000, 9, SQLT_INT);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':loan', 50000, 9, SQLT_INT);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':payment', 0, 9, SQLT_INT);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':duration', 60, 3, SQLT_INT);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':saleId', 2211445, 9, SQLT_INT); // <- this row is generating the error

// also tried these binds with no luck (same error)
//oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':code', 100);
//oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':extLoan', 20000);
//oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':loan', 50000);
//oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':payment', 0);
//oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':duration', 60);
//oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':saleId', 2211445);

$desc = oci_new_descriptor($this->connection, OCI_D_LOB);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':result', $desc, -1, OCI_B_CLOB);

oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT); // <- here the error occurs...
```

Now, as You see, all of the `SQLT_INT` binds are pure integer numbers. The procedure also awaits numbers going in... but the error **`ORA-01722 invalid number`** occurs.

Now if I change

```php
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':saleId', 2211445, 9, SQLT_INT);
```

to

```php
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':saleId', 2211445, 9, SQLT_NUM);
```

the execute generates another error: `ORA-01403 no data found`.

What I have finally tried is this call:

```php
$query = '
BEGIN 
    calc(
        100,
        20000,
        50000,
        0,
        60,
        2211445,
        :result); 
END;';

$stmt = oci_parse($this->connection, $query);

$desc = oci_new_descriptor($this->connection, OCI_D_LOB);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':result', $desc, -1, OCI_B_CLOB);

oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT); // <- here the error occurs...
```

but I still get the same **`ORA-01722 invalid number`** error.

I also tried to run the query directly in `sql developer`:

```sql
DECLARE
  code NUMBER := 100;
  extLoan NUMBER := 20000;
  loan NUMBER := 50000;
  payment NUMBER := 0;
  duration NUMBER := 60;
  saleId NUMBER := 2211445;
  cclob CLOB;
BEGIN
  calc(
    code,
    extLoan,
    loan,
    payment,
    duration,
    saleId,
    cclob);
  dbms_output.put_line(cclob);
END;
```

and the statement was successfully executed while the output was outputted as supposed.

**Do You have any idea what may cause the problem???**

---

**EDIT 1:** Funny thing is that if I do in `SQL developer`

```
saleId VARCHAR2(7) := '2211445';
```

(instead of the previous `saleId NUMBER := 2211445;`)the procedure is still executed with no error, the conversion/casting succeeds...

---

**EDIT 2:**
To make sure the problem is not with the descriptor nor `CLOB` variable binding, I have tried the next call (the rest is the same):

```php
$this->db->parseQuery('
DECLARE
    code NUMBER := :code;
    extloan NUMBER := :extloan;
    loan NUMBER := :loan;
    payment NUMBER := :payment;
    duration NUMBER := :duration;
    saleId NUMBER := :saleid;
    myclob CLOB;
BEGIN 
    calc(
        code,
        extloan,
        loan,
        payment,
        duration,
        saleId,
        myclob);
    :myclob := myclob;

    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        :myclob := \'<params>
    <code>\' || code || \'</code>
    <extloan>\' || extloan || \'</extloan>
    <loan>\' || loan || \'</loan>
    <payment>\' || payment || \'</payment>
    <duration>\' || duration || \'</duration>
    <saleId>\' || saleId || \'</saleId>
</params>\';
END;');
```

Removed the bindings but the `CLOB` one and the output (`$lob->load();`) **returned the proper XML string with all the values passed in...**

I guess now it is clear that the problem lies elsewhere and the descriptor/clob biniding is OK...

Comment: At what line does it crash, in which module?

Comment: @Sebas I do not see the procedure body, just the header. Error occures after the `oci_execute()` call while by debugging I have found out that the problem is causing the `oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':saleId', 2211445, 9, SQLT_INT);` call - as pointed out by the comment...

Comment: How come the procedure name you first listed is `calc` and in your OCI examples you are calling `flashcalc`?

Comment: @Wolf Just a typo made by improper obfuscation...edited.

Comment: [This doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-new-descriptor.php) doesn't mention `OCI_D_LOB` as valid `oci_new_descriptor` type. Have you tried `OCI_DTYPE_LOB`?

Comment: @Passerby `OCI_D_LOB` refers to the same number `50` as does the `OCI_DTYPE_LOB`. The first mentioned is older but PHP recognizes it (it is there for back compatibility). If it won't recognize it, the error would occure on that line (saying that *unknown identifier was used*) and not after it when executing the query. I appreciate Your attempt but this is not the problem...

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-new-descriptor.php#55201 A 7 years ago comment, may still help...

Comment: @Passerby The **problem is not with the descriptor nor the `CLOB` value**. I have already read the same manual and mentioned the comment and I am pretty sure I am doing all the stuff the very same way...It does not matter if You bind a variable to direct `OUT` from a procedure or to a variable inbetween...

Comment: @shadyyx Since you've already tried to hard-code all ints into `parse` and still getting the same error, I don't quite understand why you insist LOB is surely not the problem. Also you never mention in your question that you've tried to "bridge" the LOB out in PHP, like the comment above did.

Comment: @Passerby OK, so now I am telling You I have tried to "bridge it" with the same result - the same error. But OK, maybe You are right and the problem could be within that LOB descriptor. But where? And why then there is `invalid number` error and if I set the type of any parameter to `SQLT_NUM` I got the `no data found` error?

Comment: @shadyyx [Error message can be misleading sometime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php#92334). `SQLT_NUM != SQLT_INT` so they can lead to different result (just tested on my PHP). If your _actual debugging code_ is as simple as you post here, I would _guess_ the problem lies somewhere else (e.g. PHP version/OCI version/etc.).

Comment: @Passerby This is not just a debugging code, it is the actual code I call (but is slightly simplified for the purposes of asking here). The PHP/OCI version is OK as I am calling other stored procedures within the same ORA server and DB with success (not mentioning common queries...).

Comment: @Passerby I guess You cannot even imagine what have I tried so far... And still nothing (or, still the same `invalid number` error)! I am totally clueless and miserable... I hate these kind of problems I cannot solve on my own...

Comment: Hi @shadyyx did you try something like this: `oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':saleId', 2211445, -1, SQLT_INT);`. I used to use ADODb class to connect to an Oracle DB

Comment: @adiego73 Of course I did... Sure instead of `2211445` value there was a variable carrying this value (it won't work otherwise). Maybe I didn't state all the things I have tried, but I have tried nearly anything (and for sure everything that came to my mind). For now nobody supposed anything I didn't tried...